# Interact with Smart Contract Function on Metamask Mobile without Internal JSON-RPC error and 0xa9 not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, blockchain, ethereum, web3js

**Describe the bug**

I try to interact with my contract function (transfer) of my BEP20 Token on Binance Smart Chain (Testnet) using Web3.JS then the result is

On Metamask Extension PC : It works ! and transaction status is Success,

But ! on Metamask Mobile App : When I press comfirm button It always get **Internal JSON-RPC error**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqeD5.jpg)

and when I try to use more gas to 0.3 BNB (12 usd) now It can press Confirm button but instead of call transfer function on my contract, **it deploy new contract with error 0xa9 not defined**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yk5nH.jpg)

**Web3 Code**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eyqV.jpg)

```
  async function sendTX() {
const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(AbiOfContract, contractAddress);

web3.eth
  .sendTransaction({
    from: account,
    to: contractAddress,
    data: myContract.methods
      .transfer("0x8479E4B295414e27a0759Eb67aA3C33dA4598eD0", 100 * 10 ** 9)
      .encodeABI(),
    gas: 75000,
    gasPrice: 50 * 10 ** 9
  })
  .then(function (receipt) {
    console.log(receipt);
  });
```

**To Reproduce this issues**

I created Codesanbox project, in order to reproduce this issues you can try to run this https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-hoover-n1e95 on Metamask App Mobile

**Devices**

- Device: Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra
- OS: Android 11 (OneUI 3.0)
- App Version: v2.6.0